# MySQL update with a subquery in safe update mode

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following database:
[image: Database model]
The following query calculates the total amount, that comes from multiplying the products prices and the respective quantity bought, from the orders that have the amount field equals to NULL:

```
SELECT SUM(i.qtde * p.preco_unitario) FROM Produtos p
    INNER JOIN ItensPedido i ON i.id_produto = p.id_produto
    INNER JOIN Pedidos pd ON pd.id_pedido = i.id_pedido
    WHERE pd.vlr_total IS NULL
    GROUP BY i.id_pedido);
```

I can update a row in the Pedidos table using the following query:

```
UPDATE Pedidos p 
SET p.vlr_total = (SELECT SUM(i.qtde * p.preco_unitario) FROM Produtos p
    INNER JOIN ItensPedido i ON i.id_produto = p.id_produto
    WHERE i.id_pedido = 1
    GROUP BY i.id_pedido)
WHERE p.id_pedido = 1;
```

But I have to re-run this query for each row that I want to update, changing the two WHERE clauses.

What I need help to is to build a query that updates all registries with NULL amount using a single query (if possible), similar to the second one. My attempt in using the first query as a subquery gives an 1093 error: using the same target table in update in the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that by changing this one line in your subquery  this will set the subquery WHERE clause to match your records in the outer table.

```
WHERE i.id_pedido = 1
```

TO

```
WHERE i.id_pedido = p.id_pedido
```

Then you can remove the outer WHERE, unless you really want to just restrict it to p.id_pedido=1

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Such a small detail. But I must add that it not runs with safe update mode enabled, giving an 1175 error. I had to disable that in configuration before executing it. Is there any other way to do it with safe udate mode enabled?

Comment: Good question. Since Safe Mode (as I understand it) requires you to define a specific criteria in the WHERE clause.  You might be able to get around it by just adding something like  WHERE true or maybe  WHERE (select = 1) and trick it that way.    (PS, if you select *accept* on the answer I get my brownie points too).  :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept it before, my bad... Well, adding the dummy WHERE still gets the error, what solved it was adding SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; before and SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1; after the query. I think there is no other way in this case.