# Updating a table without using SQL_SAFE_UPDATES

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to update some records using this query which is basically just a way to set a "state" to a customer considering their "days since last order":

```
        UPDATE customers AS c1
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT id, DATEDIFF(NOW(), agg.cdt) AS acdt
          FROM customers
          INNER JOIN
            (
              SELECT c.id AS cid, max(o.datetime) as cdt
              FROM customers AS c
              LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id = c.id
              WHERE o.state = 20
              GROUP BY c.id
            ) AS agg ON customers.id = agg.cid
          WHERE account_type IN (1, 2)
            AND deleted = 0
            AND (account_management_state IN (0, 1, 2) OR account_management_state IS NULL)
        ) AS c2 ON c1.id = c2.id
        SET c1.account_management_state = CASE
          WHEN c2.acdt <= 90 THEN 0
          WHEN c2.acdt >= 91 AND c2.acdt <= 360 THEN 1
          WHEN c2.acdt > 360 OR c2.acdt IS NULL THEN 2
          END
        WHERE c1.id = c2.id;
```

But I'm getting:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

I'm using the table key in the final `WHERE`, `c1.id` is the `customers` table key. Using `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` is not an option. I also tried using `WHERE c1.id > 0` to no avail.

Note that I tried to run the query manually changing `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`, the query it's working as expected but this is supposed to be an automatic process.

So my options are:

1. Using a single query, `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` can't be used.
2. Using Python cursors, `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` can be used. (see *SIDE NOTE*)
3. [insert an option here]
4. (I don't want to do this) Iterate over each record (using the Python ORM) and update the record. This is stupid and will take forever.

### UPDATE

Also tried:

- Using the same ID

  ```
  UPDATE
    ...
  WHERE c1.id = c1.id ;
  ```
- Adding a huge limit after each subquery (as suggested by @Akina):

  ```
  UPDATE customers AS c1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, DATEDIFF(NOW(), agg.cdt) AS acdt
    FROM customers
    INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT c.id AS cid, max(o.datetime) as cdt
        FROM customers AS c
        LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id = c.id
        WHERE o.state = 20
        GROUP BY c.id
        LIMIT 100000000
      ) AS agg ON customers.id = agg.cid
    WHERE account_type IN (1, 2)
      AND deleted = 0
      AND (account_management_state IN (0, 1, 2) OR account_management_state IS NULL)
    LIMIT 100000000
  ) AS c2 ON c1.id = c2.id
  SET c1.account_management_state = CASE
    WHEN c2.acdt <= 90 THEN 0
    WHEN c2.acdt >= 91 AND c2.acdt <= 360 THEN 1
    WHEN c2.acdt > 360 OR c2.acdt IS NULL THEN 2
    END
  WHERE c1.id = c2.id;
  ```
- A combination of both IDs:

  ```
  UPDATE
    ...
  WHERE c1.id > 0 and c2.id > 0;
  ```

None of them are working. Still getting `Error Code: 1175`.

### SIDE NOTE

This is part part of a Python/Flask process using MySQL python client and cursors. I can use `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` as long as it's done from the Python cursor. This is not working:

- Using different queries (not throwing an error, it just won't update anything):

  ```
  connection = db.get_conn()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute('SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;')
  cursor.execute(query) # from the original query
  cursor.execute('SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;')
  ```
- Using a single query (not throwing an error, it just won't update anything):

  ```
  connection = db.get_conn()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute('''
      SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
      UPDATE ...;
      SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
  ''')
  ```
- Using `BEGIN .. END` (thought I saw the light, but no), gettting a `ProgrammingError`:

  ```
  connection = db.get_conn()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute('''
      BEGIN
          SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
          UPDATE ...;
          SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
      END
  ''')
  ```

Comment: This warning came because you are using non key column to search row and update. If you exact ID or key column then this will not come.

Comment: @aviboy2006 ah! You mean inside the first `INNER JOIN`, right?

Comment: yes. This is error for safety warning to avoid updating wrong rows.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tackle this problem, took me a while just to build this query, lol

Comment: see this two option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842134/mysql-you-are-using-safe-update-mode-and-you-tried-to-update-a-table-without-a-w and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761316/mysql-update-with-a-subquery-in-safe-update-mode

Comment: Try to add `LIMIT` clause to each (sub)query with the limit over the rows amount.

Comment: Sorry guys, none of them are working. Updated the question.

Comment: what is error you are getting same one ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 yes, same error

Comment: just add where cases for the id that do nothing.

WHERE id IS NOT NULL

Should do the trick I assume.(also make sure to add a not why you have this idiotic where, otherwise you will for sure remove it when cleaning up the code in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time, but maybe has the same issue as yours and mine today.
I have solved it by committing my changes before closing my connection
just add this before you close the connection "cnx.commit()"
hope this can help out